# Django rest framework password security for <script>

Tags: django, rest, security, passwords

I have implemented user registration in Django Rest Framework but I don't know how to check for sql injection and etc.
For example a password like this: "< script>"

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def validate(self, data):
    password = data['password']
    password2 = data['password2']
    data.pop('password2')

    if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Passwords must match."})

    errors = dict()
    try:
        # validate the password and catch the exception
        validators.validate_password(password)

    # the exception raised here is different than serializers.ValidationError
    except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
        errors['password'] = list(e.messages)

    if errors:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

    return data
```

This code is in my settings:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator', #=> Default (8 characters)
    'OPTIONS': {
        'min_length': 4,
    }
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3324798/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/38523159/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/17113712/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/20468143/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/46420168/1531971 etc.

Answer (score 0):

From Django official security docs. [Security in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/)

> Django’s querysets are protected from SQL injection since their queries are constructed using query parameterization. A query’s SQL code is defined separately from the query’s parameters. Since parameters may be user-provided and therefore unsafe, they are escaped by the underlying database driver.